# Only the first video is autoplaying in carousel in Safari 11 / IOS 11

Tags: ios, video, safari, autoplay

I have a carousel with multiple videos which are set to autoplay.  I also have them muted (they don't have any sound regardless).

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-style-image">
      <div class="field-content">
        <a href="/mypage">
          <video loop autoplay muted playsinline">
            <source src="https://example.com/position1.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="https://example.com/position1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://example.com/position1.ogv" type="video/ogv">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" data-loaded="true" src="https://example.com/position1.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
          </video>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-style-image">
      <div class="field-content">
        <a href="/mypage">
          <video loop autoplay muted playsinline">
            <source src="https://example.com/position2.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="https://example.com/position2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://example.com/position2.ogv" type="video/ogv">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" data-loaded="true" src="https://example.com/position2.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
          </video>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-style-image">
      <div class="field-content">
        <a href="/mypage">
          <video loop autoplay muted playsinline">
            <source src="https://example.com/position3.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="https://example.com/position3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://example.com/position3.ogv" type="video/ogv"> 
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" data-loaded="true" src="https://example.com/position3.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
          </video>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari only the first video auto-plays. (Not sure if it is not auto-playing or just displaying the fallback image) This used to work perfectly before so I'm guessing Apple made a change in Safari in the latest update.

As a test, I changed my autoplay settings in Safari to always autoplay but the problem remains.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?